# Angular Resolver not working no provider for ()

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

I have this issue in a new project.
I have created a route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CategoriesComponent,
    },
    {
        path: ':categoryId',
        component: CategoryComponent,
        resolve: CategoryResolver,
    },
];
```

As you can see, it's trying to use a resolver, which looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Category, CategoryService } from '@situlive/angular/data';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CategoryResolver implements Resolve<Category> {
    constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Category> {
        return this.categoryService.get(route.paramMap.get('categoryId'));
    }
}
```

When I use this code, I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CategoriesModule)[() => [ -> () => [ -> () => [ -> () => [ -> () => []:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for () => [!

If I comment out the resolver like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CategoriesComponent,
    },
    {
        path: ':categoryId',
        component: CategoryComponent,
        //resolve: CategoryResolver,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'criteria',
                loadChildren: () => import('../criteria/criteria.module').then((m) => m.CriteriaModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'feeds',
                loadChildren: () => import('../feeds/feeds.module').then((m) => m.FeedsModule),
            },
            {
                path: 'fields',
                loadChildren: () => import('../fields/fields.module').then((m) => m.FieldsModule),
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I no longer get the error, but obviously nothing is resolved.
My code in my **CategoryComponent** just looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategory();
}

private getCategory(): void {
    this.category = this.route.snapshot.data.category;
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but did you try not injecting `CategoryService` in `CategoryResolver`?

Comment: You mean, take it out of the constructor?

Comment: Yes, simply have an empty constructor and return `of(null)` in the `resolve` method.

Comment: that does the same as commenting out the resolver. Are you thinking it can't find the CategoryService? It's used in other places with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to fix your routes definition. That may be the problem.
Try to change the:

```
    {
        path: ':categoryId',
        component: CategoryComponent,
        resolve: CategoryResolver,
    }
```

to :

```
    {
        path: ':categoryId',
        component: CategoryComponent,
        resolve: {
          category: CategoryResolver
        },
    }
```

Because the resolve needs to be an object and not the direct reference to the resolver as you can se [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Comment: well spotted; no idea how I made that mistake